# React Table set Header onClick-Function without disable sort-Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

How can I set an onClick-Function to my table-header without removing the sort function (useSortBy) which will be executed by clicking the Header.
Here is my code:

```
function renderTableHeader() {
  const headers = headerGroups.map(headerGroup => {
    return (
      <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
          <th
            {...column.getHeaderProps(
              column.sortable && column.getSortByToggleProps()
            )}
          >
            {(column.render("Header")}
            <span>
              <i className={determineSortState(column)} />
            </span>
          </th>
        ))}
      </tr>
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-table` sets up an `onClick` handler on the `<th>`element by this expression: `{...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}`

If you put your own `onClick` handler before it, it will be overridden. If you put it behind it, it will override the handler from `react-table`, which will break the sorting.

So you need to trigger the `react-table` handler manually in your override like this:

```
            <th
              {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
              onClick={(e) => {
                //trigger the react-table header onClick manually
                  column
                  .getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())
                  .onClick(e);

                //your onclick functionallity goes in here
                console.log("my on click");
              }}
            >
```

Comment: How can I get this to work in TypeScript? I'm getting `Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'TableHeaderProps'.ts(2339)` error.

Answer (score 0):

For v6 or below as per Docs : https://github.com/TanStack/react-table/tree/v6, we should maintain state for `sortOptions` to remember the sorting even after calling onClick Func of any methods in ReactTable.

TO achieve that:-

1.State value `sortOptions` should be updated using `newSorted` parameter from `onSortedChange` method, like this: `onSortedChange={(newSorted) => {setSortOptions(newSorted)}}`

2.State value `sortOptions` should then be passed as value to sorted attribute in ReactTable `sorted={sortOptions}`

```
const [sortOptions, setSortOptions] = useState();
<ReactTable 
sorted={sortOptions}
onSortedChange={(newSorted) => {setSortOptions(newSorted)}}
getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
          return {
            onClick: (e) => {
              // Do Something...for onCLick Event
            }
          }
        }}}
data={data}
columns={columns}
/>
```